# How to get rows from only some columns based on columns value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use Pandas to get datas from Excel. From those tables, I often need to find one or some values in only one row, based on value in a column.
I've read a lot about Pandas (doc and SO), and almost everytime, the question is like « how to SELECT * FROM df WHERE value = smthing ».
But what I'd like to do is more like :

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM df
WHERE Col3.value = smthing
```

And I can't find any answer.

For example :

```
>>> dataFrame

   foo  bar  sm_else
0    0    3        6
1    1    4        7
2    2    5        8
```

I want to get foo value and sm_else value when bar == 4.
So :

```
foo  sm_else
1       7
```

Result can be DataFrame or can be list or dict, I don't really care.

Thanks !

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

df.loc can help you out

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2, 3], 
                        'col2': [4, 5, 6], 
                        'col3': [7, 8, 9]})
print(df.loc[df['col2'] == 4][['col1', 'col2']])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Tried a lot of formats but never succeeded in finding the good one, and never found an example on SO or on doc…

Comment: Can someone explain to me the diff between AlexMTX answer and David Smolinski's one ? df.loc[boolean][[col1, col2]] and df.loc[boolean, [col1, col]] ?

Comment: @Groflo I bet the David's loc is more effective, because it does the job through one operation. In my case I first filter the required data in the first step, and filter columns in the second step

Answer (score 2):

```
df.loc[df.bar == 4, ['foo', 'sm_else']]
```

Comment: Didn't even realize that name of column can be object by its name ! thanks for your answer and for that.